# Alternatives to Geektool that make desktop content clickable?

Tags: macos, desktop, geektool

Does anybody know of any alternatives to [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) that allow you to put content on your desktop sourced from shell scripts, files, etc but that makes the content interactive?

A few use cases I would really like:

- A list of recent tweets where any links in the tweets are clickable
- A calendar widget that allows me to navigate forward and back in months
- A search box for google or wikipedia
- An app launcher

I know you could use Dashboard widgets for this but I prefer to have these right on the desktop itself. Also Dashboard widgets seem more limited in what they're able to do, but I'm less educated about these so I could be wrong.

[Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/cms/) does all this by the way, but is Windows only.

Comment: How do people ever have their desktops showing, anyway? :)

Comment: @jtbandes 4×5k displays, obviously! 

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Ubersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/). It shows contents as widgets on desktop. Widgets are configured through `coffee` or `js` scripts. You could also other scripting languages like `python`, `shell` etc.  These widgets are interactive through optional keys.

There are already a handful of [widgets](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht-widgets/) are available. More details regarding the project can be found at their github.

Comment: As of v0.6 the developer made widgets ‘clickable-by-default,’ i.e. what the @Marplesoft wanted; but he's reverted the behaviour as of v0.7 due to problems making it reliable: http://tracesof.net/blog/2015/11/29/clickable-widgets-experiment/

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo! Widgets](http://widgets.yahoo.com/download/) has a mac version available, and a quick search shows an application launcher, twitter client, a month calendar, and a wikipedia and google search box.

If you want to use dashboard widgets, [this software](http://deepitpro.com/en/mac/products/DesktopWidget/info/index.shtml) claims to make your dashboard widgets stay on the desktop. It does cost money, but they have a free trial available.

Comment: The OP states that he doesn't want Dashboard widgets. Also, you can [turn on developer mode for the Dashboard](http://www.ijailbreak.com/news/mac-tweak-putting-the-dashboard-on-your-desktop-how-to/). Note that you'll need to disable the Dashboard as a space (System Preferences>Mission Control)

Comment: With developer mode though, the widgets stay on top of your other applications